# installation errors on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey,

I have been trying to install Gazebo on ubuntu 12_10 and have been getting the following wrror:

rushabh@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install gazebo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gazebo

Can anyone help please ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1190/installation-errors-on-ubuntu-12.10/) by [rdd0101](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/194/rdd0101/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ubuntu 12.10 binary packages of Gazebo are currently under development. They will be released as soon as possible.

Currently we only have binary packages for Ubuntu 12.04. Other distributions will have to compile from source.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1